# Maven Build Failure with "mvn install" command

Tags: java, maven, cmd, automation, maven-surefire-plugin

I was trying to generate and test my codes (if working) for Cucumber-Maven report then opened command prompt. I have tried "mvn clean", it was BUILD SUCCESS. After that, I have tried "mvn install" and encountered BUILD FAILURE (error was shown).

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.844 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-05T13:14:51+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.20: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.20 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to webproxy.sample.com:8080 [webproxy.sample.com/205.165.7.13] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                    <projectName>ExecuteCucumberMavenAF</projectName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports-html</outputDirectory>
                    <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                    <enableFlashCharts>true</enableFlashCharts>
                    <buildNumber>42</buildNumber>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>   
</plugins>  
</build>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you st a wrong Proxy: *Connect to webproxy.sample.com:8080 [webproxy.sample.com/205.165.7.13] failed: Connection timed out: connect*

Comment: you should check and update your proxy in setting.xml.

Comment: IMHO surefires versioning is only three parts. Therefore version is not 2.22 but 2.22.0. By the way 2.22.1 is already out.

Comment: @Jens i have my proxy in settings.xml but still i encountered this error: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.22.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 1]

Comment: @vivekdubey i have my proxy in settings.xml but i still encountered an error. do i really need to set-up proxy for an automation project? the proxy that i am using that time was from my company. how would i handle that proxy if i'm running my automation framework at home?

Comment: @wumpz i have updated surefire into 2.22.0 but i still encountered an error.

Comment: @AutomationEngineer your are sure the Proxy Settings are correct? try to run maven with `-X` to get more informations

Comment: Are you positive that this is indeed your proxy: webproxy.sample.com/205.165.7.13

Comment: @Jens yes, i'm sure. is settings.xml must be in .m2 folder? i have tried running mvn -X, error was encountered: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.

Comment: @wumpz i've only used "sample" to hide the real proxy that i am using.

Comment: @AutomationEngineer -X should be added to your nvm command.

Comment: @Jens how to do that?

Comment: simply call `mvn -X install` or which goal you need

Comment: @Jens i have encountered an error: Connection timed out: connect. i think there's problem with my proxy. do i really need to set-up proxy for an automation project? the proxy that i am using was from my company.

Comment: @AutomationEngineer As Long as you do not have an local maven repository you need to setup a proxy, because maven will download some files wich are needed to execute your bild, like the maven-cucumber-reporting` `plugin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like proxy issue which is blocking the downloads of dependencies, so make some changes in `settings.xml` or create a one if it is not there.

Goto `c:\users\youruser\.m2\settings.xml.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

 <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>user</username>  <!-- Put your username here -->
      <password>pass</password>  <!-- Put your password here -->
      <host>123.45.6.78</host>   <!-- Put the IP address of your proxy server here -->
      <port>80</port>            <!-- Put your proxy server's port number here -->
      <nonProxyHosts>maven</nonProxyHosts> <!-- Do not use this setting unless you know what you're doing. -->
    </proxy>    
  </proxies> 
</settings>
```

Comment: if proxy doesn't have username and password, should i leave it blank or comment it?

Comment: @AutomationEngineer , leave it blank.

Comment: do i really need to set-up proxy for an automation project? the proxy that i am using that time was from my company. how would i handle that proxy if i'm running my automation framework at home?

Comment: Click **Start**, click **Run**, type `cmd`, and then click **OK**.  At the command prompt, type `netsh winhttp reset proxy`, and then press **ENTER**.

Comment: result: Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied. Current WinHTTP proxy settings: Direct access (no proxy server).

Comment: run CMD with admin rights, i mean right click on cmd icon and select **Run as Admin**

Comment: i still encountered this error: Current WinHTTP proxy settings: Direct access (no proxy server).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using eclipse. I used maven clean and install for the same POM file. It is working fine.

Seems there is some issue with your `C:\users\youruser\.m2\settings.xml` file.
May be proxy issues which is blocking maven from downloading dependencies. 
Please check your settings.xml file.

Comment: never specify hard coded path but try to give clues so that users can change it according to their PC settings.

Comment: @Debi P i have my proxy in settings.xml but i still encountered an error. do i really need to set-up proxy for an automation project? the proxy that i am using that time was from my company. how would i handle that proxy if i'm running my automation framework at home?